# Iframe width does n't auto expand in new Facebook timeline view

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

I have a facebook application which lists a list of categories in an iframe in facebook page. In the old facebook view, it is fit to the width where the iframe width is 520px. But when the page is opened in the new Timeline view, it's width is still 520px.
Since the function FB.Canvas.setAutoResize() is now deprecated by Facebook, I tried using FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(). But still, it is not working.

Can any one please suggest a solution to auto adjust the canvas in both facebook page with timeline installed and without that??

Thanks...in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this in the settings of application:

[image: Page Tab Application settings]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. So I would like to know that, will it be working also in the facebook profiles without timeline installed??

Comment: No, it will not, and the width for the Pages without timeline will be still 520px. On *March 30, 2012* all pages will be transitioned to use Timeline and this will no longer be an issue...